# Function to merge excel data referencing a count using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a function that merges multiple rows of text in a column into a single cell based on a pre determined count. My goal is to generate a flexible function to aid in compiling / interperting large quantaties of data. The code I've written returns #NAME? and I cant figure out where the error is. My code is as follows:

```
Function vmrg(countref As Integer, datref As Integer) As String
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -countref)) Then % check if cell containing count is blank
vertmerge = "N/A"                                % if blank, state N/A
Else
    Dim datlst(0 To ActiveCell.Offset(0, -countref).Value - 1) As String 
    Dim i As Integer                                                      
    For i = 0 To ActiveCell.Offset(0, -countref).Value - 1  
        datlst(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(i, -datref).Text  %fill array with data
    End
    vertmerge = datlst(0)
    For i = 1 To ActiveCell.Offset(0, -countref).Value - 1  % merge array to a single string
        vertmerge = vertmerge & ", " & datlst(i)
        End
   End
End Function
```

I have matlab and some C++ experience but this is the first time I've used VBA so my syntax is probably odd in some areas and wrong in others.  Ideally I would like to reference the cells where the data and count info are stored, but for now I'm hoping to correct my syntax and set a jumping off point for further development of this function. Any reccomendations are appreciated.

Code Rev_1: I still have an output of #NAME? but I think I've corrected(?) some of the issues

```
Function vertmerge(countref As Range, datref As Integer) As String
If IsEmpty(countref) = True Then
vertmerge = "NA"
Else
Dim datlst(0 To countref.Value - 1) As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To countref.Value - 1
datlst(i) = countref.Offset(i, datref).Text
Next i
vertmerge = datlst(0)
For i = 1 To countref.Value - 1
vertmerge = vertmerge & ", " & datlst(i)
Next i
End
End Function
```

Comment: FYI, In VBA the comment character is a single-quote, not "%".

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads up. I only added in the comments in the post to clairfy the intended purpose of the code, so they won't have a bearing on the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some dangerous things here!

First - you are referencing "ActiveCell" from inside a function; but you have NO IDEA what cell will be active when the function runs!  Instead, pass the target cell as a parameter:

```
=vmrg("B6", 5, 6)
```

and change your function prototype to

```
Function vmrg(r as Range, countref as Integer, datref as Integer)
```

Now you can reference things relative to r with

```
r.Offset(1,2)
```

etc.

Next - you are never assigning anything to `vmrg`. In VBA, the way a function returns a value is with (in this case)

```
vmrg = 23
```

You are assigning things to a variable called `vertmerge` - but that is not the name of your function. At least add

```
vmrg = vertmerge
```

Just before returning. That might do it. Without a full sample of your spreadsheet I can't help you more.